# Categorical Pasting Lemma

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

If I'm not mistaken, the pasting lemma for a two-element open cover $X=A\cup B$ of a topological space is equivalent to saying that the following square is a pushout in $\mathsf{Top}$: $$\begin{matrix} A\cup B & \longleftarrow & B \\ \uparrow && \uparrow \\ A & \longleftarrow & A\cap B\end{matrix}$$ where the arrows are the canonical embeddings.

Is my statement true, and if so, how can I categorically formulate the pasting lemma for general open covers $ \left\{  U_i\right\}  _{i\in I}$?

Comment: @Exterior It is true in the special case you consider. For the $n > 2$ case you need a very different diagram.

Comment: The general case should probably just be the colimit of the diagram consisting of the disjoint union of the pairwise intersections $U_i \cap U_j$, mapping by the inclusions into the $U_i$, since defining a function $\bigcup U_i \rightarrow T$ is the same as defining functions $U_i \rightarrow T$ that agree on overlaps.

Comment: @ZachL. could you please post a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ be an open cover of $X$. Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the poset of subsets of $I$ of size $1$ or $2$, ordered by inclusion, and consider the diagram $V : \mathcal{J}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Top}$ sending each $J \subseteq I$ to $\bigcap_{j \in J} U_j$. Then $X \cong \varinjlim_{\mathcal{J}} V$. (Just check the universal property!)

What is essential in the above is that each $U_i$ is open in $X$. On the other hand, you might like to verify for yourself that we can replace the poset of subsets of $I$ of size $1$ or $2$ with the poset of non-empty finite subsets of $I$.

Comment: 1. I have not seen an expression of the form $\varinjlim _{\mathcal J}V$ before, is this what is known as a filtered limit? 2. Is the equality $X \cong \varinjlim_{\mathcal{J}} V$ topologically equivalent to the pasting lemma in the sense that each implies the other?

Comment: $\varinjlim$ simply denotes the colimit. Your claim is the case where $\left| I \right| = 2$.

Comment: So the notation $\varinjlim _{\mathcal J}V$ just makes explicit the diagram. How about equivalence to the pasting lemma?

Comment: Just write out what it means.

Comment: I'm writing things out now, but I'm confused about the functoriality of $V$ - its action on inclusions should give me "restriction functions" in $\mathsf{Top}$, but I don't see how to define them.. For instance $V(u):U_i\rightarrow U_i \cap U_j$ should be the identity on $x\in U_i \cap U_j$, but what should it be on $x\notin U_i \cap U_j$?

Comment: $V$ is a functor $\mathcal{J}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Top}$. So you should be defining $U_i \cap U_j \to U_i$ instead.

Comment: I thought that by "ordered by inclusion", one means there's an arrow $J\rightarrow J^\prime$ iff $J\subset J^\prime$, so iff $J\supset J^\prime$ in the opposite category. Is the convention the other way around?

Comment: Read the definition of $\mathcal{J}$ _carefully_.

Answer (score 2):

If $X = \bigcup_k U_k$, the thing you want to do is express $X$ as a quotient of the disjoint union $\coprod_k U_k$ of the open sets by the equivalence relation $P_i \sim P_j$ whenever $P \in X$ appears both in $U_i$ and $U_j$.

(My topology-fu is rusty; make sure the above claim is correct in general! Or at least in the generality you care about)

We can express this with a coequalizer. For each $i$ and $j$, we define a pair of functions $U_i \cap U_j \to \coprod_k U_k$: $f_{ij}$ is the inclusion of $U_i \cap U_j$ into the copy of $U_i$ in the disjoint union, and $g_{ij}$ is the inclusion into $U_j$.

To get this for all of the intersections at once, we take the disjoint union of all the intersections. We get two different maps

$$ \coprod_{ij}( U_i \cap U_j) \to \coprod_k U_k $$

one corresponding to applying $f$ to each component of the disjoint union, and one corresponding to applying $g$ to each component of the disjoint union.

Every instance $P \sim Q$ of the equivalence relation appears as $P = f(x)$ and $Q = g(x)$ for some $x$ in the domain, and conversely we always have $f(x) \sim g(x)$. Therefore, the coequalizer is the quotient of $\coprod_k U_k$ by $\sim$, which is isomorphic to $X$.