# Open coverings and (co)limits

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

My question concerns general topology and category theory. Let $X$ be a topological space, and consider an open covering $\{U_{i}\}$ of $X$. Is it possible to view $X$ as a (co)limit of the $\{U_{i}\}$ in the category $\mathsf{Top}$ of all small topological spaces, and continuous functions between them? Special cases, as well as bibliographical references and counterexamples are also welcome. Please note that category theory and topology are not my field.

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081949/5191).

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, $X$ is the colimit of the diagram whose nodes are the $U_i$ and the intersections $U_i \cap U_j$ and whose edges are the inclusions $U_j \cap U_i \leftarrow U_i \to U_i \cap U_j$. The colimit cocone consists of the inclusion maps $U_i \to X$ and $U_i \cap U_j \to X$. The universal property boils down to the following fact that one can "glue" functions:

> Let $f_i : U_i \to Y$ be a family of continuous functions with $f_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$. Then, there is a unique continuous function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f|_{U_i}= f_i$ for all $i$.

Proof: We must define $f(x):=f_i(x)$ for $x \in U_i$, and this is well-defined because of $f_i(x)=f_j(x)$ for $x \in U_i \cap U_j$. To check contunity, observe that for open subsets $V \subseteq Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(V) = \cup_i f_i^{-1}(V)$ is a union of open subsets, hence open, too.